# Dialog-like activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I am looking to display a Dialog with a list of data. 
I came across this article: http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2010/01/android-dialog-or-is-it/
It claims that it is better to define it as an activity and then use the Theme.Dialog.

Is this correct?

I am not expecting any feedback from the user - it is an info-only screen.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can create a custom dialog and then you can create your separate layout or XML file ,inflate that XML to that dialog and then you can show anything in the dialog that you have in that XML.

Or you can even use this techniques, [custom dialog with list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250765/android-custom-list-dialog)

Comment: Thing is that I am trying to do this from a CursorAdaptor and the only way I know of connecting it is by defining the class as an sub-class of ListActivity and using setListAdapter - as shown in the Notepad example. I am sure there is a correvt way of doing this but I can't seem to find it. I have my CursorAdapter defined but just can't see how to fill in data in the dialog.