# ListView items does not respond in a custom dialog box

Tags: android, listview, customdialog

I am developing an app which is displaying some data to a ListView. The data is perfectly shown in the ListView (custom list view). i have used a custom adapter also which is extended by a BaseAdapter. i have modified my app to pop up a custom dialog box when some duplicated records are there in the list view. so my problem is the items in the custom dialog (in the list view ) does not respond to the onclick listener

here is my code (which is inside the adapter class)

```
        public void showDuplicateDialog(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        LayoutInflater infl = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = infl.inflate(R.layout.dialog_list, null);

        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogList);

        //NewsRowAdapter nw = new NewsRowAdapter(mContext, activity, R.layout.dialog_row, list);

        SimpleAdapter sim = new SimpleAdapter(mContext, list, R.layout.dialog_row,  new String[] { STIME,END, DATE }, new int[] {
                R.id.stime2,R.id.etime2, R.id.blank2});

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "item clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        /*ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, android.R.id.text1, Names);*/

        alertDialogBuilder2.setView(view);
        alertDialogBuilder2.setAdapter(sim, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "item clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })



        .setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        alertDialogBuilder2.show();
    }
```

can someone tell me where the problem is ?

i have refer the developer instructions also.. they stated that below code should work..
but it is not responding at all.. no errors..no exceptions..but doesn't works

```
alertDialogBuilder2.setAdapter(sim, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "item clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })
```

please help me

Comment: Your list view should be in context of you custom dialog box. Try this

Comment: @AndroidHacker can you explain it more further please ?

Comment: Check out my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371218/how-to-set-a-custom-list-view-into-a-dialog-box/20371447#20371447

Comment: Share your "dialog_list.xml". do you have any buttons on that xml file. If so, It will capture the click event.

Comment: no there is no buttons inside it...just image view and some text views...

Comment: Your list view code is correct. There's no problem in that. Just check out my post

Comment: i have refered your post.. my problem is i have an arrayList like this

 
[{Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}, {Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}, {Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}, {Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}, {Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}, {Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}] 

in my dialog box i just want to show these items.. that is why i use and adapter...what should i do.. ?

Comment: Code defined in my post fulfills all your requirement. For that certainly need an adapter and all other stuff required for creating custom dialog with custom list view

Answer (score 1):

If you are display custom layout including ListView then no need setAdapter on AlertDialog.

Just setAdapter on ListView Instead of AlertDialog.

```
public void showDuplicateDialog(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        LayoutInflater infl = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = infl.inflate(R.layout.dialog_list, null);

        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogList);

        //NewsRowAdapter nw = new NewsRowAdapter(mContext, activity, R.layout.dialog_row, list);

        SimpleAdapter sim = new SimpleAdapter(mContext, list, R.layout.dialog_row,  new String[] { STIME,END, DATE }, new int[] {
                R.id.stime2,R.id.etime2, R.id.blank2});

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "item clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        /*ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, android.R.id.text1, Names);*/

        alertDialogBuilder2.setView(view);
        lv.setAdapter(sim); // Set Adapter to listview




        alertDialogBuilder2.setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })


        alertDialogBuilder2.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        alertDialogBuilder2.show();
    }
```

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

You can also use default functionality instead of custom view..

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
         // Do something with the selection
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

[check this for more about alertdilaog.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: i have done it...but still cant catch the click event in the list view  :(

Comment: but i have to load the data thru the JSON..i have get the data from my service and holding by a ArrayList...just want to handle the click event... still it doesn't works.... :(

Comment: Are data appear in listview ??

Comment: yes...successfully... i just need to handle the onclick event on the list :(

Comment: my arraylist like this [{Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}, {Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}, {Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}, {Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}, {Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}, {Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}] how can i convert this to char sequence ?

Comment: set **android:focusable="true"** on all item of view in listview

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 final CharSequence[] items = { "Facebook", "Twitter", "Email" };
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
     builder.setTitle("Share");
     builder.setItems(items,    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,    int item) { 



     if (items[item].equals("Facebook")) {  

     } else if (items[item].equals("Twitter")) {

     } else if (items[item].equals("Email")) {

        }
   });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
  alert.show();
```

Comment: my arraylist like this 


[{Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}, {Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}, {Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}, {Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}, {Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}, {Date=11/18/13, EndTime=09:00 AM, StartTime=08:00 AM}]

how can i convert this to char sequence ?

Comment: please help me some way :(