# Customized Dialog in Android

Tags: android

I want to make the exact dialog box as given in this picture : [image: Customized dialog box]

How do I achieve the same look and feel, can anyone suggest please.

Comment: Try my post .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371218/how-to-set-a-custom-list-view-into-a-dialog-box/20371447#20371447 . It contains all you need.

Comment: details in dialog are static or dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

It's not too tricky :) You need to create a custom dialog. You'd begin by extending [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) and overriding the onCreate method.

Within this custom dialog class you can use `setContentView` to assign a specific layout file to that dialog class, in which you can manipulate the contents however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate xml file for your dialog look.
on the button click of your activity call this dialog

here is link to tutorial related to dialog implementation in android

[Tutorial 1](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

[Tutorial 2](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDialogs/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's just a straight forward xml layout, the only trick is to have layout background a transluent png with rounded corners, and disable border on your dialog

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dip"
        android:background="@drawable/popup_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    //add list items here

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:onClick="dismissPopUp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_close_btn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```